# Ask Permission not shown on kitkat

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am learning about request permission on runtime. My phone OS is kitkat. This is my code :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf("com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"), 1000)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

But permission dialog not shown. Is there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: runtime permission in after lollipop OS.stating from Marsha mallow.

Comment: Permission is necessary in Marshmallow & above versions. Below 6.0 Permission is automatically taken by device. That's why it is not showing in your kitkat device.

Comment: so is this blog wrong? https://blog.protektoid.com/android-permissions-kitkat-lollipop-and-marshmallow

Comment: @zihadrizkyef permissions will be asked while you install the app in kitkat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not ask runtime permission below **Android 6.0**

Below Android 6.0 all permisson are granted while user install the app

**FYI**

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app

Read about **[runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)**

Comment: so is this blog wrong? https://blog.protektoid.com/android-permissions-kitkat-lollipop-and-marshmallow

Comment: @zihadrizkyef read from docs **https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html**

Answer (score 1):

Kitkat(version 20)
 or below versions of Android don't need runtime permission requests,you can just define the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file and that will be enough for the permissions.

example : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

**BUT**

For Lollipop(version 21) or higher version you need to add method to request permissions for your Application.

Answer (score 0):

Android developer site quote,

> In Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

Run time permissions are added in Android *Marshmallow*. Android versions prior to marshmallow will ask for permission during the app installation.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to learn more about android runtime permissions

Answer (score 0):

According to the [google developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

Which means that your phone are required to ask for runtime permissions from API level-23, i.e, Marshmallow whereas KitKat is API level-19. So, no runtime permission will be asked by the Operating system.